# Is there a way to block an element with another element without giving it a background?

Tags: html, css

I wanted to create a layout that when an element overlaps another element, the other element should be blocked or cut off. I have a background image so I can't assign the elements backgrounds.

Is this possible to do with css? Those element could be anywhere and moves sometime so I'm not sure I can achieve it with `clip-path`.

Is there a way to achieve this?

```css
.container {
  background: url(https://www.k9web.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/adorable-shiba-inu-dog-lying-on-the-sofa-1536x1024.jpg) center/cover no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 240px;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 54%;
  left: 54%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Text 1</span>
  <span>Text 2</span>
</div>
```

What I want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: You can't do this with pure CSS. You have to get the position of Text 2 with JS and set the clip-path of Text 1 via JS accordingly. At least in theory this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Anyway, I found a workaround that utilizes `mix-blend-mode: darken`. But it loses the ability to draw any bright color. Since I'm only gonna draw some black texts so it works for me:

```css
.container {
  background: url(https://www.k9web.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/adorable-shiba-inu-dog-lying-on-the-sofa-1536x1024.jpg) center/cover no-repeat;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 240px;
}

.wrapper {
  mix-blend-mode: darken;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-color: white;
  line-height: 26px;
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  top: 55%;
  left: 55%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <span>Text 1</span>
    <span>Text 2</span>
  </div>
</div>
```